# AWS Amplify + Flutter: How to do CI/CD?

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-deployment, github-actions

### Background

I am using AWS Amplify to build an app that uses S3 and Amplify authentication. I want to use CI/CD to automate deploying for people who only want to learn Flutter.
I setup my project in the following way:

1. I built a project in Amplify Studio, and `amplify pull`'d it to local.
2. There, I put a flutter project in the same folder, which uses the amplify configuration file (lib/amplifyconfiguration.dart) to understand how to log in and what S3 stuff I use.
3. Then I pushed this project to GitHub, connected GitHub with Amplify frontend, and can trigger a build.

### Problems with this setup

There are a few problems with this setup, that don't work as I hoped.

- The `amplifyconfiguration.dart` file is not checked into git. This is for good reason, as the backend may change without git knowing. The file is merely a result of the backend.
- This means that I need to `amplify pull` (I think) to get the file. This means I need the amplify CLI.
- My standard flutter container does not contain Amplify CLI
- Amplify's build environment does not contain flutter
- The Amplify CLI relies on interactive user input to configure as a flutter project as far as I have been able to figure out

### My approaches

I tried to solve my problem in the following ways:

#### Github Actions

[Somebody on Medium suggested to use GitHub Actions to build the project,](https://medium.com/flutter-community/hosting-flutter-web-applications-with-amplify-hosting-and-github-actions-d53ba213767) to then commit using Actions to include the `flutter build web --release` output, to trigger an automatic build on Amplify to only use the artefacts produced by the GitHub build. I figured out the Amplify config, but the GitHub Actions config was more difficult. The problem lies in the configuration file, as I need to get it using amplify pull.  Here is the snippet that failed for me:

```yaml
      - name: Amazon Web Services CLI
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v3
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: eu-central-1

      - name: Amplify
        run: |
          npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
          if [[ "${{ github.ref }}" != "refs/heads/stable" ]]; then
            export AWS_ENV_NAME=dev
          else
            export AWS_ENV_NAME=prod
          fi
          amplify configure project --envName $AWS_ENV_NAME --appId ${{ secrets.AWS_APP_ID }} --providers "{\"awscloudformation\":{\"accessKeyId\":\"${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}\",\"secretAccessKey\":\"${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}\",\"region\":\"eu-central-1\"}}"
```

This part opened a browser window to login, which of course does not work on a runner that is not interactive.

#### Amplify Build

The second approach was building everything on Amplify. Since the AWS image does not have Flutter installed, I tried to install it with the following code:

```yaml
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build commands
    pre_build:
      commands:
    build:
      commands: 
        - echo "Installing flutter"
        - mkdir -p /usr/local/
        - curl -sL https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_3.13.1-stable.tar.xz 
        - tar xf flutter_linux_3.13.1-stable.tar.xz -C /usr/local/
        - export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/flutter/bin"
        - flutter doctor
        - echo "Getting amplify config"
        - export AWS_APP_ID="abcdefgh"
        - if [ "${AWS_BRANCH}" = "stable" ]; then
            amplify pull --appId ${AWS_APP_ID} --envName prod --yes;
          else
            amplify pull --appId ${AWS_APP_ID} --envName dev --yes;
          fi
        - flutter pub get
        - flutter build web --release
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: build/web
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths: []
```

This failed in the tar command:  `[WARNING]: tar (grandchild): xz: Cannot exec: No such file or directory`.
Apparently xz wasn't installed. So I tried installing it with yum:

```
2023-08-27T14:15:14.328Z [INFO]: # Starting phase: build
                                 # Executing command: yum install xz
2023-08-27T14:15:18.466Z [INFO]: Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
2023-08-27T14:15:31.947Z [INFO]: Resolving Dependencies
```

However this build got stuck in this phase. No further log was there, just a runner doing nothing.

### Question

What is the best approach to do this, and what should I change to make it work?

Thanks for reading, if you can help me, thanks a lot!